# Bypass/replace event/handler for a VB.NET Windows Forms control I didn't create?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I'm working on a project that has needed a TreeView control with multiple columns. After research looked like a custom control was necessary, and to my luck I found a good one on CodeProject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26849/The-TreeListView-To-End-All-TreeListViews

I've been leaning on this control heavily but have run into a few bugs that have been very challenging to work around given that I can't actually access the source code in the project files the developer was kind enough to share. The main issue I'm dealing with is a crash that pops up when the control is resized almost to the point to where a horizontal scrollbar would need to appear. I noticed that when resizing there is a deadzone of about 10 pixels where this control would show the horizontal scrollbar slightly before you'd need to, likely because of weirdness in measuring the indenting widths of child tree nodes. In this state the scrollbar appears, the scroll box fills the entire bar and won't allow you to scroll left or right.

This doesn't bother me other than the fact that if you use your mouse scroll wheel in this state it throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception and pulls my application down:

> Value of '-1' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between
>   'minimum' and 'maximum'.

I'd love to be able to handle this exception but I'm quite new to VB.NET and Windows Forms and am still learning how events are handled. If there is a straightforward way to override the OnMouseWheel event or otherwise handle errors that may be triggered from it that would be fantastic. That or any other suggestions the community may have would be greatly appreciated.

If helpful, here is the top part of the error's StackTrace:

> System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
>   WinControls.ListView.ContainerListView.OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)

The ListTreeView control (one I'm using) inherits from ContainerListView. ContainerListView's OnMouseWheel event is protected. Does this mean that I won't be able to override it?

Thanks, and happy to provide any other information that is needed.

Comment: The source code IS provided, it's the second download link.

Comment: @Aybe You're absolutely right, but unfortunately it is under source control and I haven't been able to open the project file. Could be user error on my end but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: If you're talking about that message box about solution being bound to a TFS server ... Start from scratch, unzip the archive, remove read only attributes for all files, open solution, say no, ok, ok -> the solution will load.

Comment: Well in that case sounds like user error. In any case I figured overriding the event wouldn't be difficult vs. going to the source, but perhaps I'm wrong. What would you suggest? Any straightforward ways of going about this? I'm just starting to warm up with VB.NET and could use all of the advice I can get.

Comment: If method is overridable then no need to go edit sources, just do your stuff before base method call, else, get your hands dirty.

Comment: @Aybe, to confirm - if the event is protected will this prevent me from overriding it?

Comment: If it is not `virtual` then it is not overridable. Not that the author should have made those first like `OnSelectionChanged`. Typically the base method would fire an event which you might not want to raise depending your needs.

Comment: Alright sounds like I may have to dig through source code. Thanks for the help - will leave this up in case someone has a different solution that may be straightforward.